# GoogleのChrome extensionのドキュメントが間違っている？

Tags: google-chrome

どこに書けばいいかわからなかったのでここに書きますが、Googleのドキュメントが間違っているようです。
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onActivatedには
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function callback)のcallbackの引数はactiveInfoというtabId、windowIdのプロパティを持つオブジェクトのはずなのですが、それに従ってコードを書くと、

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener((activeInfo) => {
    chrome.tabs.get(activeInfo.tabid, (tab) =>{
        chrome.storage.sync.get('pages', (result) => {
            if(!result || !result.pages){
                chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({"text":""}, () => {})
                return;
            } 
            const detail = result.pages[tab.url];
            if(detail){
                chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({"text":detail.interval}, () => {})
            }
        })
    })
})
```

No matching signatureエラーが起きます。
ところが[この記事](https://qiita.com/Yuta_Fujiwara/items/daf41429f95caec82982#tabs)では

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function (tabId) {
    chrome.tabs.query({"active": true}, function (tab) {
        console.log(tab[0].url); // 切り替わったタブのURL
        chrome.tabs.remove(tab[0].id); //切り替わったタブを削除
    });
});
```

と書いてあり、これの通りに書くとエラーが起きず正常に動きます。
公式のドキュメントが間違っていることなどあり得るのでしょうか？
また、その場合どこに報告すれば良いでしょうか？

Comment: ドキュメントの誤り指摘については、ページ最下部に "Report a content bug" があるのでこちらを利用する形になるかと思います。

Comment: 「この記事」のコードと公式ドキュメントはとくに矛盾していないように見えます。lamrongol さんが書いたコードを示していただかないと、ドキュメントの間違いかどうかは判断できません。

Comment: 自分が書いていたコードを載せました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    chrome.tabs.get(activeInfo.tabid, (tab) =>{
```

ドキュメントによると、正しくは、`tabId` (i が大文字) です。

```
    chrome.tabs.get(activeInfo.tabId, (tab) => {
```

Comment: こんなカンタンなミスだっとは……。activeInfoではなくtabIdでも動く謎は解けないままですがありがとうございます。

Comment: 仮引数には好きな名前をつけられます。「この記事」のコードで tabId を参照するには tabId.tabId と書くことになるでしょう。

Comment: なるほどそういうことですか……